# a background grid appears after using ps2pdf

Tags: pdf, display, postscript

Morning, everyone, 
Quick question about PS2PDF. I use it to convert graphics that I produce directly in postscript to PDF. While there is no visual problem on PS files, I see a grid on my PDF viewer. At first I thought the problem was in the viewer, but it remains present when I compile my TeX files containing the figures with PDFLaTeX. Do you have any ideas for settings that can "fix" this display? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd need to see the original PostScript file. What are you using to view the PostScript program results ? What are you using to view the PDF ? If you post an example file (and link to it here) I can look at the program. By the way, I assume that by ps2pdf you mean the script provided with Ghostscript, and you are actulaly using Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device to do the work, not some other program.

Comment: I'm using the basic PDF viewer of Ubuntu 18.04, for both extensions. I only used the basic "ps2pdf input.ps output.pdf" expression, without any extra parameters. And yes this is the script provided by Ghostscript, sorry for the lack of informations.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what the basic PDF viewer of Ubuntu is, Okular maybe ? I'm not sure how you are viewing PostScript files with anything other than Ghostscript to be honest, its not like there are a lot of open source PostScript interpreters to choose from. I'd have to guess that whatever that viewer is, its using Ghostscript to either render the PostScript or create a PDF from it, which is what you are doing... If you post the PostScript file somewhere I'll take a look.

Comment: It seems that the basic Ubuntu viewer is Evince, it is independant of Ghostscript. 
I uploaded the PS file here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/acf1237de54ab0e8352bb3b296ca035420200414123818/05e43a

Answer (score 0):

Evince is independent of Ghostscript as far as PDF files are concerned, but I don't know how it can be viewing PostScript files.

I believe what you are seeing is an artefact of the PDF rendering engine in use, and the way the PDF file is constructed (which is itself dependent on the way the PostScript is constructed).

Much of the content is drawn by creating little rectangles which are intended to butt up against each other (and basically do). However, depending on the resolution, the precise numerical accuracy of the calculations and the accuracy of the co-ordinates, it can be the case that these rectangles do not quite touch ideally. There is a theoretical gap between them.

You can see this occur with Adobe Acrobat, and zooming in and out changes where the lines appear (it changes the effective resolution, thereby changing the calculations from user space to device space, ie to the actual pixels on screen).

I cannot say for sure that the same problem exists with Evince, but I expect it does. Withh Acrobat I can turn off anti-aliasing, which is where the problem really arises. Acrobat is attempting to insert an anti-aliased pixel between the two rectangles, which leads to these faint lines. Turning it off (In Acrobat X Edit->Preferences->PageDisplay->Smooth Line art) makes the lines disappear.

Ghostscript doesn't apply anti-aliasing by default, so these lines don't appear when rendering either the PostScript or the PDF files, but if I turn on anti-aliasing (-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4) then Ghostscript renders the lines in both the PostScript and the PDF file.

Essentially I think the problem is that your PDF viewer is using anti-aliasing and your PostScript viewer isn't, so they don't look the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
Indeed when opening the PDF file with Ghostview, the problem is no longer present. So I could use Ghostview to view the PDF of my LaTeX file and print it from there to avoid those unsightly lines on my final document.

Comment: And thank you also for explaining things so precisely, it's always nice to be able to understand what's going on behind file conversion stories! :)

Comment: I'm glad you could follow me, I wasn't certain I was explaining it very clearly. I'm not sure about printing the file, that's CUPS and I don't really understand CUPS very well.